# Is it OK to dress as a stewardess on a flight?

Tags: legal, airlines, airport-security, clothing

My client is not a stewardess. Her man has a stewardess-attraction, and normally it's no problem, but when they fly together she feels jealous. I'd like to advise her, "the attraction is part of him; don't be jealous, help him focus it on yourself".

One way would be, when they fly, she dresses as a stewardess herself. We'll draw a veil over how she'd proceed from there - my question is, does dressing as a member of aircrew when you are not one cause any problems?

Is it legal? If so, would it cause the aircrew concern?

Comment: This might be more common than you think. I've seen the roles you have described and also the reverse: where the man dressed as a 'pilot', but also as a chauffeur and butler.  As long as the apparel is commercially available and there's no attempt at impersonation, then fine.  Adult games...  Cosplay...

Comment: The logical solution would be to dress as a stewardess *from a different airline.*

Comment: (1) <joking_mode = 1>; Getting a new man sounds worth considering :-) (2) Informal comment only: I'd agree with Gayot and DJC in principle but, even if legal, I'd think that  there was enough potential for misunderstanding or embarrassment that trying to dress "like a stewardess" enough to be useful for the desired purpose, while being clearly enough distinguished as not being one to anyone in the airline industry seems liable to be a good idea. Quite how that can be achieved is tbd. Perhaps including 'stewardess like' behavioural aspects as well as attire would help. ...

Comment: ... (3) Can somebody talk to my wife and give her a few pointers in this general area. Not necessarily stewardesses,  ....  [NB: :-) :-) :-) :-) ]

Comment: I can now imagine an aircraft full of passengers in pilot and hostess uniforms on their way to a cosplay event!

Comment: Ha! Reminds me of Agatha Christie's *Death in the Clouds*.

Comment: You could also consider dressing as a stewardess from an earlier era.

Answer (score 5):

It is ok to dress "like" a stewardess on a flight. That is to say, it is okay to wear a dress or clothing similar to what stewardesses would wear.

Now stewardesses also wear pins, badges, etc. for identification. These are the items that separate the "real thing" from "counterfeits." Don't wear these accouterments to actually identify yourself as something you're not.

In short, it's probably ok to "counterfeit" a stewardess as long as it's not too "real."

Answer (score 4):

It really depends how well the uniform matches. I have inadvertently looked nearly identical to one of the male cabin attendants, right down to the glasses and (lack of) hair. Passengers were asking me all kinds of questions, and in most cases I knew the answers, so...  The real attendant thought it was hilarious.

However, in normal lighting no one would confuse me for the real thing. If you get a completely accurate uniform, right down to the lapel pins and scarf you could end up chatting with security for a while - they are a little sensitive about what would appear to them to be impersonating someone with a security clearance. Off-duty FAs do not wear their uniforms in the cabin.

Comment: Worth commenting that in some jurisdictions it may be against the law to impersonate flight personnel.

Answer (score 0):

She can dress like stewardess, may look similar with her dressing. there will some things which will differentiate her from the real steward and the crew wont have any  concern. the real steward got pin etc.... (look unique).